# How to debug multiple clients connecting to server application?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, client-server

I wrote a Client that will connect to my WCF service, and the service will able to handle multiple client application connections.

So when I first start testing it, I configured Visual Studio to start multiple projects to start up both my client and WCF service project in Visual Studio.

Then because I want to test if it works when I have *multiple* client applications connected to my service, I start up another client application manually (double...click on exe).

So yeah, of course the client application that I started up manually won't be able to debug in Visual Studio, and it does have strange things goes on.  So is there any advice for debugging in situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch the additional clients separately, and then in a new instance of Visual Studio (with the project loaded), go to the Debug menu and select "Attach to Process" to start debugging the new client.

Comment: Do I have to start up in a new instance of Visual Studio?  Is it possible to do it in same instance?

Comment: Yes, I think you do need to start a new instance. As long as you have enough memory and processing power, it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is the option to [set multiple startup projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019):

- In Solution Explorer, select the solution (the top node).
- Choose the solution node's context (right-click) menu and then choose Properties. The Solution Property Pages dialog box appears.
- Expand the Common Properties node, and choose Startup Project.
- Choose the Multiple Startup Projects option and set the appropriate actions.

---

Anyway, I often debug LoB apps consisting of server and client and come across this compelling necessity all the time, when I only want to debug one of them while keeping the other on between sessions.

What I do is I first set the current startup project using the top toolbar (see screenshot) to the insignificant one (if I'm currently working on the client, it would be the server, or vice versa), then "Start without debugging" (Usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

[image]

Then, I switch the startup project to the client I want to debug, and hit F5 or other debugging method I'm interested in.
Somewhat tedious, but it's the quickest and works for me the best so far.

There are some petitions to Microsoft to make this feature easier so that they should add a command like "Start instance without debugging", so that you don't have to set the startup project back and forth all the time. Please vote [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/460160/start-new-instance-without-debugging.html), and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/875077/add-a-start-without-debugging.html).